# Why does the debugger fail and test pass unless done() callback invoked?

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, callback, jasmine

1) Can anyone explain why, when debugging this jasmine test for hapi, the debugger never hits any breakpoint inside the injected section (see comment) unless done is called later on? How can the absence of a line of code that is not yet reached affect the debugger earlier on ?

I am aware that it is important to call the done method (which I have commented out on purpose). I am however surprised by the consequences.

2) Another unfortunate side-effect of forgetting to call the done method is that the test always passes. Instead of passing I would rather see it fail if I make an error. Any suggestions?

```
const server = require("../lib/server");
describe("Server hello", function () {
 it("returns status code 200", function (done) {
  server.inject({ method: 'GET', url: '/' }, (res) => {
   // Never reached if done uncommented - even by debugger breakpoint - why?");
   console.log("GOT " + res.payload);
   expect(res.statusCode).toBe(200);
   // done(); // Test always passes if uncommented - is there any way to force an error instead?
  });
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[Read the source, Luke!](https://blog.codinghorror.com/learn-to-read-the-source-luke/) Jasmine [docs](https://jasmine.github.io/edge/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support) for asynchronous testing note:

> This spec will not start until the done function is called in the call to beforeEach above. And this spec will not complete until its done is called.

So if you don't call `done` your suite is not run, **not** that it runs and times out!